# Do I have to recompile boost library if I modify `boost\format\alt_sstream_impl.hpp`

Tags: boost

I need to modify the following file in boost library
`c:\boost\vs2010_boost1.49\include\boost\format\alt_sstream_impl.hpp`

Based on [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)

The only Boost libraries that must be built separately are:

```
Boost.Filesystem
Boost.IOStreams
Boost.ProgramOptions
Boost.Python (see the Boost.Python build documentation before building and installing it)
Boost.Regex
Boost.Serialization
Boost.Signals
Boost.Thread
Boost.Wave
```

Question> Is alt_sstream_impl.hpp one of them?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me (looking at the 1.49 release) that 'alt_sstream_impl.hpp' is part of the Boost.Format library, and therefore, you will not need to rebuild your boost libraries.

It is possible (but not that likely) that one of those libraries that has to be rebuilt uses Boost.Format, but I didn't see any evidence of it.